# Can't send php mail from AWS linux machine

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email

I've written following code in php in my AWS linux machine, however it can't send emails

```
    $to = "test@abc.com.au"; // E-mail address of reciever
    $subject = "Test Subject"; // Subject of email
    $body = "Hi All, <br><br> This is the test email <br><br>Thank You!";
    $header = 'From: test@abc.com.au';

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
            echo "Email sent successfully!";
    } else {
            echo 'Email send Failed';
    }
```

The email sending like above always fails. Following is my setting of php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
SMTP = "my smtp server address"
smtp_port = 25
```

Interestingly, if I send email using following command, it is successfully received

```
echo "hello" |sendmail -s -v "test" test@abc.com.au
```

Can someone please help and advise, what could be causing mail function to fail?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *How* does it not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Don't get anything.. just 'Email send Failed' in Console..

Comment: Is there anything in the system logs (perhaps /var/log)?

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar. Yes, finally found the error.. The error message is:

    sendmail[5232]: vA33eK7e002718: to=<test@240>, ctladdr=<user@hostname> (501/501), delay=4+23:48:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=11220275, relay=240, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Name server: 240: host name lookup failure

Comment: OK. updated /etc/sysconfig/network file and added my proxy mail server address in hostname. Then restarted the service..

Now, I can send emails, but the php server isn't using proxy mail server to send emails. Instead, it is sending emails directly from the machine

Comment: why don't you use ses ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding "Smart" relay host in /etc/mail/sendmail.cf  file.

Following are the steps I took

```
sudo vi /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

Search for DS and updated the file like below

```
#"Smart" relay host (may be null) 
DSsmtp.myserver.local
```